# Accessing CloudFoundry user-provided services using Spring Cloud connectors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

I'm trying to use Spring Cloud to consume a generic REST service from a Cloud Foundry app.

This service is created using Spring Boot, as follows:

```
package com.something;

@RestController
public class DemoServiceController {
    @RequestMapping("/sayHi")
    public String sayHi() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

This works fine - I can access `http://www.example.com/srv/demo/sayHi` and get "Hello!" back.

Next, I created a user-provided service instance using the CF-CLI and bound it to my app. I can now see the bound service in `VCAP_SERVICES`.

```
cf cups my-demo-service -p '{"url":"http://www.example.com/srv/demo/"}'
cf bs my-demo-app my-demo-service
```

Next, as described [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/tree/master/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector#connecting-to-generic-services-1), I added this bean to my app's Spring config, with the `connector-type` set to my original controller (I have a reference to it as well).

```
<cloud:service id="myDemoService"
               service-name="my-demo-service"
               connector-type="com.something.DemoServiceController"
               />
```

Now when I auto-wire `"myDemoService"` into my app,

```
@Autowired
private DemoController myDemoService;
```

I get an error:

> No services of the specified type could be found.

I've made sure to include all required dependencies, including `spring-cloud-spring-service-connector` and `spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector`.

What's going wrong here? Am I giving the wrong bean parameters? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try a regular service and not a user provided service?  Just want to try to isolate if the issue is with both kinds of services.

Comment: @JeffSloyer It will still need to be a custom service. The built-in ones all have specific annotations in spring-cloud-connectors.

Comment: Thats fine, I just wanted to check to see if its related to being a user provided service or a regular service.  Can you try a regular service and see if the behavior is the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Cloud Connectors won't know what to do with this service, as each supported service must be of a known type (MySQL, Postgres, Redis, MongoDB, RabbitMQ, etc). Setting the `connector-type` to your Controller class won't do what you want.

What you will need to do is to create a custom Connectors extension. Here's an example of a project that does that: https://github.com/cf-platform-eng/spring-boot-cities.