# No suitable ServiceConnectorCreator found error - Spring cloud/CloudFoundry

Tags: java, spring, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

All,

I have a spring boot app that gives me an error, when I try to push to IBM Bluemix/CloudFoundry.

This is a spring boot app, using spring cloud and trying to connect to a relational db service (sqldb which is a cloud version of DB2) service.

I could connect without spring cloud, where I explicitly specified the db credentials from vcap_services in my property file. However I am trying to avoid that using spring cloud abstraction, but gets the error mentioned below.

My expectation is the spring boot/cloud should identify the test-sqldb service I bound to the app and create a data source on the fly. Instead I get the error given below when I do cf push.

Is it fair to assume that spring boot/cloud pair will orchestrate the data source for me as I have the db2 driver jar and attached service in environment.? If not, can some one point to me what am I missing?

**Pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependenc

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc </artifactId>
        <version>10.5</version>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have following config in spring context file as given below as mentioned in [this](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html) link.
Using the cloud profile to separate from my local datasource config.

**spring config** - this is imported to my spring context and is in effect when I run with cloud profile

```
<beans profile="cloud">
    <cloud:data-source id="dataSourcePref" service-name="test-sqldb">
        <!-- <cloud:pool-data-sources>
            <value>TomcatJdbc</value>
            <value>TomcatDbcp</value>
            <value>BasicDbcp</value>
        </cloud:pool-data-sources>-->
    </cloud:data-source>
</beans>
```

**Spring Boot Application Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:/META-INF/spring/my-jpa-beans.xml")
public class JpaTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(JpaTestApplication.class, args);
    }
 }
```

**Error**

```
    2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT 2015-10-28 16:47:11.115 ERROR 29 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error registering service factory; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No suitable ServiceConnectorCreator found: service id=test-sqldb, service info type=org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo, connector type=interface javax.sql.DataSource
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cloud.config.xml.CloudServiceIntroducer.postProcessBeanFactory(AbstractCloudServiceFactoryParser.java:90)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:177)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:607)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at com.example.JpaTestApplication.main(JpaTestApplication.java:14)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No suitable ServiceConnectorCreator found: service id=test-sqldb, service info type=org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo, connector type=interface javax.sql.DataSource
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cloud.ServiceConnectorCreatorRegistry.getServiceCreator(Cloud.java:356)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cloud.Cloud.getServiceConnector(Cloud.java:255)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cloud.Cloud.getServiceConnector(Cloud.java:142)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cloud.service.AbstractCloudServiceConnectorFactory.createService(AbstractCloudServiceConnectorFactory.java:103)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cloud.service.AbstractCloudServiceConnectorFactory.createInstance(AbstractCloudServiceConnectorFactory.java:98)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cloud.service.AbstractCloudServiceConnectorFactory.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractCloudServiceConnectorFactory.java:93)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.cloud.config.xml.CloudServiceIntroducer.postProcessBeanFactory(AbstractCloudServiceFactoryParser.java:82)
2015-10-28T09:47:11.11-0700 [App/0]      OUT    ... 16 common frames omitted
2015-10-28T09:47:11.26-0700 [DEA/17]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
```

Comment: Please post the VCAP section for that service with sensitive information masked. It's impossible to tell what service type the connector thinks it's dealing with from just a stack trace.

Comment: (Also, have you tried with just plain `@CloudScan`, not specifying the details like you did in your XML?)

Answer (score 3):

Seems I understood what is happening.

An answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555505/accessing-cloudfoundry-user-provided-services-using-spring-cloud-connectors) thread mentions about Service connectors that gave me a hint.

SqlDb need DB2DataSourceCreator which was not available in spring-cloud-connectors version 1.1.1-release, which I was using. It supports others like MySQL, Postgres, Redis, MongoDB, RabbitMQ, etc..

Upgraded to 1.2.0-release and I am able to pass this error point. 
Thanks for two of you who tried to help.